# How to reduce the amount of WordLift's logs?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordlift

Our web site logs are full with many WordLift's related events.

Specifically we see many lines like these in the error_log file:

`[21-Aug-2018 16:17:04 UTC] TRACE  [Wordlift_File_Cache_Service             ] Trying to get cache...
[21-Aug-2018 16:17:29 UTC] DEBUG  [Wordlift_Entity_Post_Type_Service       ] Registering post type entity...
[21-Aug-2018 16:17:31 UTC] TRACE  [Wordlift_Cached_Post_Converter          ] Post 963 relations changed, invalidating cache...`

How do I limit WordLift's logging?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that debug is enabled and WordLift is logging trace, debug, info, warn and error messages to the PHP logging facility (which is called error_log, hence the general misunderstanding that they're all errors).

To filter WordLift logging level, add the following to the wp-config.php file (3 = log warnings and errors, 4 = log only errors):

`define( 'WL_LOG_LEVEL', 3 );`